# User Profile Creation on User model's post_save signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth, django-signals

I have UserProfile model that I instantiate whenever a User is created by using post_save signal everything is working fine except the ImageField in the userprofile. I am using django-allauth for signup and login. When I try to access the profile page of any user, the console repeatedly prints this :

```
[28/Dec/2016 12:22:06] "GET /media/C%3A/Users/shagu/Desktop/zorion-develop/project_1
/media/profile/images/Users/shagu/Desktop/zorion-develop/project_1/media/profile/images/...
```

and says this is the end

```
    ../zorion-develop/project_1/media/profile/images/nobody.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[28/Dec/2016 12:24:26] code 414, message Request-URI Too Long
[28/Dec/2016 12:24:26] "" 414 -
```

The profile model is as follows :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(width_field="width_field",
                              height_field="height_field",
                              upload_to=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'media', 'profile','images'),
                              default = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'media', 'profile','images', 'nobody.jpg'),
                              )
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(
        choices=(
            ('M', 'male'),
            ('F', 'female'),
        ),
        default='M', max_length=1)
    profile_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

settings related to media are as follows :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(PROJECT_ROOT))
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

And this is how I am trying to access the image in my template :

```
<div align="center"><img alt="User Pic" src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" id="profile-image1" class="img-circle img-responsive">
```

I am kinda new to django. Please let me know where I am messing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just little less info that needed to fully understand and fix your problem, but I can give you a hint that will probably fix it.

First of all, your MEDIA_ROOT in the current state points outside of your project, because PROJECT_ROOT is probably something like '/home/user/myproject' and MEDIA_ROOT will be '/home/user'. Anyway that's fine if you actually wanted it to be. But actually I would change it to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
```

Second, using absolute path in your

```
upload_to=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'media', 'profile','images')
```

is not actually a good practice. You should use relative path and Django will actually build correct path (and link in the future) relatively to MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL. Like this:

```
upload_to=os.path.join('', 'profile','images')
```

After you do supposed fixes, upload a new file/image for your image field, because I suppose Django already store links in your db in a wrong way and highly recommend clean testing.